# Pybind11: Wrap a struct with a pointer member?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, pybind11

I have the following struct I need to wrap

```
struct dataStruct {
    const std::vector<int>& data;
    bool valid_data = true;
}
```

In my wrapper file, under `PYBIND11_MODULE` and so forth I have

```
py::class_<dataStruct>(m, "dataStruct")
   .def(py::init<>())
   .def_readwrite("data", &dataStruct::data)
   .def_readwrite("valid_data", &dataStruct::valid_data);
```

I'm getting two errors

```
no instance of function template "pybind11::class_<type_, options...>::def_readwrite [with type_=dataStruct, options=<>]" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (const char [7], <error-type>) -- object type is: pybind11::class_<dataStruct>

pointer to member of type "const std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>> &" is not allowed
```

I know this is due to the pointer in the struct, but when looking at the pybind11 documentation I could not find out how to deal with pointers when they are within a struct.

Comment: Python uses reference counting, so using a raw reference to a `std::vector` is a no-go. On top of that, a reference is a pointer that cannot be modified, so creating a read/write property for a reference is already misguided. It would be helpful to better understand your motivation. Are you trying to create a binding for a struct (`dataStruct`) that contains a vector (`data`) whose contents can be modified from python?

Comment: Essentially I have this c++ library (I didn't write it) that I want to fully expose to python, this is a slightly simplified version of one of the data structs within it (original just has more struct members). I don't think I strictly need it to be writable, but definitely readable. C++ is not my strength so my goal was just to create a close as possible 1:1 binding in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I have done before is to write a wrapper struct around `dataStruct` that you expose to Python. This will allow you to keep an extra copy of the vector as an actual Python list.

```cpp
struct dataStructPy : dataStruct {
    const py::list & data_py;
}
```

You can then set `data_py` as a property instead of a readwrite and you can write get/set functions that do a conversion between `std::vector` and `py::list`. This allows you to use a `std::vector` on the C++ side while using the standard Python `list` on the Python side. Such functions might look like:

```cpp
py::list dataStructPy::data_py_get()
{
    py::list list;
    for(const auto & x : this->data) {
        list.append(x);
    }

    return list;
}

void dataStructPy::data_py_set(const py::list & data_py)
{
    this->data.clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < py::len(data_py); ++i) {
        this->data.emplace_back(data_py[i]);
    }
}
```

You can then expose `dataStructPy` to Python and call it `dataStruct` (you can see we still expose `&dataStruct::valid_data`):

```cpp
py::class_<dataStructPy>(m, "dataStruct")
   .def(py::init<>())
   .def_readwrite("valid_data", &dataStruct::valid_data);
   .add_property("data", &dataStructPy::data_py_get, &dataStructPy::data_py_set);
```

In Python, doing the following

```py
x = dataStruct()
x.data = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

will result in the C++ `x.data_py = py::list{1, 2, 3, 4};` and `x.data = std::vector{1, 2, 3, 4};`

**NOTE:** This only works for the assignment operator (=). If on the Python side, if you do `x.data[3] = 5` ***it will not update the C++ vector***, to do that you would need to create an object that accesses the vector's memory from Python using the [] operator.