# pybind11: Automatic conversion of python list to std::vector<dataStruct>?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, stdvector, implicit-conversion, pybind11

I have this

```
struct dataStruct {
  int val1;
  int val2;
}

struct topStruct {
  int someData;
  std::vector<dataStruct> dataVector;
}
```

Here is my binding code (I've excluded the very standard boilerplate, I can add it in if it would be helpful) note pybind11 namespace rename -> `namespace py = pybind11`

Also I have the following included

`pybind11/pybind11.h`
`pybind11/stl.h`
`pybind11/complex.h`

```
py::class_<dataStruct>(m, "dataStruct")
  .def(py::init<>())
  .def_readwrite("val1", &dataStruct::val1)
  .def_readwrite("val2", &dataStruct::val2);

py::class_<topStruct>(m, "topStruct")
  .def(py::init<>())
  .def_readwrite("someData", &topStruct::someData)
  .def_readwrite("dataVector", &topStruct::dataVector);
```

In python I'm looking to create the `topStruct` and fill out the members

```
import bindedlib

topStruct = bindedlib.topStruct()

dataStruct1 = bindedlib.dataStruct()
dataStruct1.val1 = 11
dataStruct1.val2 = 22

dataStruct2 = bindedlib.dataStruct()
dataStruct2.val1 = 44
dataStruct2.val2 = 88

# below is the problem
topStruct.dataVector = [dataStruct1, dataStruct2]
```

---

```
>>TypeError: (): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
1. (self: bindedlib.topStruct, arg0: std::vector<dataStruct, std::allocator<dataStruct> >) -> None
```

---

So the problem clearly is that the list isn't getting converted properly, so my question is if there is something I could do in the binding to get automatic conversion, so that I could just assign a list to the `dataVector` member.

I know one alternative is create a function that would manually convert the python list to `std::vector<dataStruct>`, but ideally I'd like to be able to use the `topStruct.dataVector = [dataStruct1, dataStruct2]` syntax in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same strategy as here [Pybind11: Wrap a struct with a pointer member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68292760/pybind11-wrap-a-struct-with-a-pointer-member/68304644#68304644). Write a wrapper for `topStruct` that exposes dataVector as a `py::list`, then write the setters and getters:

```py
struct topStructPy : topStruct {
    py::list dataVectorPy;
}

py::list topStructPy::data_vector_py_get()
{
    py::list data_vector_py;
    for(const auto & x : this->dataVector) {
        data_vector_py.append(x);
    }

    return data_vector_py;
}

void topStructPy::data_vector_py_set(const py::list & data_vector_py)
{
    this->data.clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < py::len(data_vector_py); ++i) {
        this->data.emplace_back(data_py[i]);
    }
}

py::class_<topStructPy>(m, "topStruct")
   .def(py::init<>())
   .def_readwrite("someData", &topStruct::someData);
   .add_property("dataVector", &topStructPy::data_vector_py_get, &topStructPy::data_vector_py_set);
```